# Converting IDs from three to four digits

Tags: r, replace

I have a sample inventory with hundreds of samples looking like this:

```
       ID Value
1  ABC001     1
2  ABC002     1
3 ABC1004     1
```

I would like to convert the ID column so that all numbers have four positions, like this:

```
        ID Value
1  ABC0001     1
2  ABC0002     1
3  ABC1004     1
```

I initially tried a simple sub function like this:

```
df$ID <- sub("ABC", "ABC0",df$ID)
```

But this doesn't do the job because I already have some IDs with four positions, so I end up with some IDs having five positions:

```
        ID Value
1  ABC0001     1
2  ABC0002     1
3 ABC01004     1
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for a function  to solve this?

Thanks so much!

Example df:

```
df <-   data.frame(ID = c("ABC001", "ABC002", "ABC1004"), Value = c(1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: `stringr::str_replace(df$ID, "\\d+$", function(x) stringr::str_pad(x, width = 4, pad = "0"))`

Comment: I reopened as the dupe target could not be applied in this situation